# Refer to self in Capybara 'within' block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I want to perform operations on a Capybara node, and on one of its children nodes:

```
find('#some_parent_node').click
find('#some_parent_node').find('.some_child_node').click
```

I tried to put them together in a `within` block like this:

```
within('#some_parent_node') do
  page.click
  page.find('.some_child_node').click
end
```

but `page.click` turned out not be the correct way to do it. How can I apply Capybara methods like `click` to the very node that is referred to as the argument to `within` (i.e., `'#some_parent_node'`)?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `page.`  inside within block?

Comment: what are you expecting from `page.click`?

Comment: @fabersky I am expecting it to be equivalent to doing `find('#some_parent_node').click` outside of the `within` block.

Comment: This should be doing exactly what you want, what makes you think it's not, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, looks a whole lot like the block takes an optional argument that is the element.

```
within('#some_parent_node') do |element|
  element.click
  find('.some_child_node').click
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In a `within` block you operate on the parent node *by default*, so there's no need to prefix commands with `page`, and the following should work:

```
within('#some_parent_node') do
  click
  find('.some_child_node').click
end
```

There are a few more examples in the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Awithin).

Comment: Hm, I thought the same, but it isn’t working for me…

Comment: Results in `undefined local variable or method 'click'`